# Connect to erlang remote shell running in SSL mode

Tags: ssl, erlang, erlang-shell

I have an erlang application which is running in SSL mode with mutual authentication. I tried to remsh to it after supplying the required options(certificate, key, cachain etc) but failed. What is the correct way to connect to remote erlang shell in SSL mode?
PS: I am using erlang 17.3

Comment: What about more information what you did and what you expect. Add step by step receipt what you did.

Comment: Section 4 of [Erlang in Anger](https://www.erlang-in-anger.com/) has some details about connecting to remote nodes. Are you doing what's described in section 4.3, or something entirely different?

Comment: Thanks all for the response. I know I haven't given full details here. I was following documentation, but was launching erlang shell in embedded mode, something like erl - boot start_ssl -mode embedded - hidden - name abc - remsh node <some ssl options>. This failed with error saying could not find 
crypto:supports, when I Changed mode to interactive it worked